# Evaluation of a sum of integers raised to a power

Tags: calculus, approximation

Let $1 \leq \alpha < +\infty $ be a real number and $n \geq 1$ be a positive integer, then the following sum

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^\alpha
$$

in general has no explicit form. Is there a way to approximate such sum with approximation error bounded uniformly with respect to alpha?

Comment: ther is the exact result $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\alpha}= \zeta (-\alpha)-\zeta (-\alpha, n+1) $$ using riemann zeta and hurwitz zeta function

Comment: It is also the generalized harminc number $H_n^{(-a)}$

Comment: Faulhaber's formula can be used to evaluate it. In this case it would be $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha + 1} \sum_{j=0}^{\alpha}(-1)^{j} {{\alpha+1}\choose{j}} B_j n^{\alpha+1-j}$$ Where $B_j$ are the Bernoulli numbers